# Make Snapshot of Main OS

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, kali-linux, snapshot, parrot-os

Can I make snapshot(something like that) of my main os/host machine(Which in this case is parrot os) ? Because when I use my parrot within a month or so I end up with broken os(because of my tinkering)! That's why I thought something like snapshot that I can use by removing my broken system and use that saved image on the go. Installing and updating new system from the fresh is just laborious.

Comment: "Snapshot" is a term applied to virtual machines. You need to use one of the commercial backup applications and back your system up to a USB drive.

Comment: Okay sir understood !